# Dynamic Addition of Row in Laravel Blade using Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload, dynamic

This is my blade ---

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="content" id="app">
    <!-- Lock Forms -->
    <!-- <h2 class="content-heading">Add User</h2> -->
    <!-- Register Forms -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Bootstrap Register -->
            <div class="block block-themed">
                <div class="block-header bg-gd-dusk">
                    <h3 class="block-title">Add Cashout Details</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    @include('errors.error')
                   {{--  <form action="{{ route('cashoutdetails.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> --}}
                    <form @submit="formSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                    @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Select Store</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="store_id" v-model="form.store_id">
                                   <option v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id" v-bind:value="store.id">@{{store.channel_id}}</option>
                                </select>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Recorded Date</label>
                                <input type="text" class="flatpickr form-control" v-model="form.recorded_date" name="recorded_date"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Total Closing Report</label>
                                <input class="form-control" v-model="form.closing_report_total" type="number" name="closing_report_total" placeholder="Enter Closing Report Total">   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Total Deposit</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="form.total_deposit" name="total_deposit" placeholder="Enter Total Deposit">   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Difference</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="form.difference" name="difference" placeholder="Enter Difference" readonly>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" v-if="form.difference != 0" >
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="cashoutexpenses.amount" name="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount">   
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="cashoutexpenses.explanation" name="explanation" placeholder="Enter Explanation">  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <input class="form-control-file" type="file" v-on:change=""> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="button" value="Add Row" @click="addRow()"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Prepared By</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="prepared_by" v-model="form.prepared_by">
                                    <option v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" v-bind:value="user.id">@{{user.name}}</option>
                                 </select>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Deposited By</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="deposited_by" v-model="form.deposited_by">
                                    <option v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" v-bind:value="user.id">@{{user.name}}</option>
                                </select>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Date of Deposit</label>
                                <input type="text" class="flatpickr form-control" v-model="form.deposit_date" name="deposit_date"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Deposit Reference Number</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="form.reference_number" name="reference_number" placeholder="Enter Reference Number">   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Upload Bank Receipt</label>
                                <input class="form-control-file" type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange">   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>Comments</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" v-model="form.comments" name="comments" placeholder="Enter Comments"> </textarea> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Bootstrap Register -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function() {
    },
    computed: {
        difference: function() {
            return this.form.difference = this.form.closing_report_total - this.form.total_deposit;
        }
    },
    data: {
        stores: {!! $stores !!},
        users: {!! $users !!},
        form: {
            closing_report_total : '',
            total_deposit: '',
            difference: '',
            user_id: '',
            deposited_by: '',
            deposit_date: '',
            prepared_by: '',
            recorded_date: '',
            reference_number: '',
            comments: '',
            image: '',
            store_id: ''
        }, 
        cashoutexpenses: {
            amount: '',
            explanation: '',
            image: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onImageChange(e){
            console.log(e.target.files[0]);
            this.form.image = e.target.files[0];
        },
        addRow() {
                this.cashoutexpenses.push({
                    amount: '',
                    explanation: '',
                    image: ''
                });
        },
        formSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentObj = this;

            const config = {
                headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            }

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', this.form.image);
            formData.append('store_id', this.form.store_id); 
            formData.append('recorded_date', this.form.recorded_date); 
            formData.append('closing_report_total', this.form.closing_report_total);
            formData.append('total_deposit', this.form.total_deposit);
            formData.append('difference', this.form.difference);
            formData.append('prepared_by', this.form.prepared_by);
            formData.append('deposited_by', this.form.deposited_by);
            formData.append('deposit_date', this.form.deposit_date);
            formData.append('reference_number', this.form.reference_number);
            formData.append('comments', this.form.comments);
            axios.post('/cashoutdetails/store', formData, config)
            .then((response) =>{
                console.log(response);
            })

            .catch(function (error) {
                currentObj.output = error;
            });
        }
    }
})

</script>
```

below is the controller code to store the data -

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //return $request->all();
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(storage_path('app/public/bankreceipt'), $imageName);
        $cashout_details = CashOutDetail::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'store_id' => $request['store_id'],
            'recorded_date' => $request['recorded_date'],
            'closing_report_total' => $request['closing_report_total'],
            'total_deposit' => $request['total_deposit'],
            'difference' => $request['difference'],
            'prepared_by' => $request['prepared_by'],
            'deposited_by' => $request['deposited_by'],
            'deposit_date' => $request['deposit_date'],
            'reference_number' => $request['reference_number'],
            'bank_receipt'=> $imageName,
            'comments' => $request['comments']
        ]);
        /* return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Details added!',
        ], 201); */ 
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Details Saved Successfully!'); 
    }
```

Now, i have three issues ---

1. AddRow function should create a new dynamic row containing columns for amount, explanation and an image.
2. bank reciept is storing null in database
3. after saving the record, it is not navigating back to index page.

Comment: Concerning #3: You will have navigate to a new page with javascript after your axios post. You can use something like `window.location = '/home'`

Comment: Ok thanks ! Can you also help for first two ?